# Как узнать кодировку текстового файла

Tags: java, кодировка, text

Есть программа которая обрабатывает текстовый файл. Нужно перед открытием и работой с файлом чтобы программа проверила кодировку текста. Подскажите как это реализовать, я только начинаю осваивать Java, буду признателен за пример кода.

Comment: Берем ваш вопрос, переводим на английский, вбиваем в гугл, открываем первую ссылку, копируем код, вставляем в свой проект.

Comment: @metalurgus ну если бы я мог так сделать разве я бы спрашивал? есть конкретные примеры? за ссылку буду признателен.

Comment: Что из вышеизложенного алгоритма вызывает у вас проблемы?

Comment: @metalurgus уровень английского не позволит правильно поставить вопрос а тем более разобраться в найденном материале

Answer (score 2):

Вообще это непростая задача и я думаю не всегда возможно это сделать. Обычно кодировку определяют заранее. Но действительно (как и сказал @metalurgus) довольно много информации в сети.
Хотя, нужно понимать, что для решения такой задачи понадобится использовать какую-нибудь стороннюю библиотеку думаю вот это рассуждение подходит: [определение кодировки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759356/what-is-the-most-accurate-encoding-detector)

Comment: это все очень геморно выглядит, может я не стой стороны зашол. ситуация такая, программа открывает и обрабатывает текстовый файл, но файл может попасть в любой кодировку, нужно или проверять кодировку чтобы не было крякозябр или как то запретить обработку если файл не подходит под конкретную кодировку.

Comment: @TСPakko и это просто так не запретишь (на файле не написано в какой кодировке там символы), только если читать и выкидывать ошибку разбора фала, если у него есть какой-то определённый формат (xml, css и т.д.)...

Answer (score 1):

Коллеги уже писали, что единого рецепта как бы нет, но я таки попытаюсь описать примерный паттерн решения этой задачи:

1) Получаем список поддерживаемых данной платформой кодировок 
`Charset.availableCharset()`

2) Берем первую по списку `charset` и читаем строчку из файла:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), charset));         
String line=br.readLine();
```

3) Берем Yandex Словарь и оформляем [JSon запрос lookup](https://tech.yandex.ru/dictionary/doc/dg/reference/lookup-docpage/), запоминаем статистику переводов

4) После прогона всех доступных кодировок выбираем ту, которая получила наилучшую статистику - это и будет наша искомая кодировка.

Answer (score -2):

`java.io.OutputStreamWriter.getEncoding()` метод возвращает имя кодировки символов, используемых потоком