# При запуске java файла в sumblime и win cmd разная кодировка

Tags: java, cmd, sublime-text, кодировка

Имеется файл txt, который я считываю и вывожу на экран. Если он в ansi кодировке по умолчанию, cmd выводит русский текст корректно, а sublime text 3 кракозябры. 
Sumblime настраивал так
[RunJava.sublime-build]

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac $file && java $file_base_name"
}
```

Если файл сохраняю в UTF-8, sumblime выводит корректно, а cmd напротив кракозябры. 
Где поглубже разобраться с этим всем? И как в данном случае решить наскоро проблему - чтобы и там,и там текст выводился корректно? Когда код java с русскими String литералами я выводил в cmd, мне помогали ключи -encoding utf8, но если речь заходит о utf8 файле, то не прокатывает.
Скрины прилагаются
[image: Первый случай]

[image: и второй случай]

Answer (score 1):

**Для sumblime**

> "Preferences -> User-Settings"

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Mac Classic.tmTheme",
  "fallback_encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)",
  "font_size": 10,
  "update_check": false
}
```

**Для Java**
Мне кажется, это ответ на твой вопрос 
[Клац](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458454/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Если от себя, то вот как указать кодировку консоли

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"));
System.setErr(new PrintStream(System.err, true, "UTF-8"));
```

---

Явно указать кодировку, можно, например, в конструкторе InputStreamReader и в конструкторе OutputStreamWriter:

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)

OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream out, String charsetName)
```

---

Если хочешь создать строку

```
String str = new String (Массив байт,"UTF-8");
```

---

Если хочешь поменять кодировку файла

```
private final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

    public static void swapEncode(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try (final FileInputStream    fileInputStream    = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
             final InputStreamReader  inputStreamReader  = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, "windows-1251");
             final FileOutputStream   fileOutputStream   = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
             final OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, "utf-8"))
        {
            final char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int readed;
            while ((readed = inputStreamReader.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                outputStreamWriter.write(buffer, 0, readed);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Меню File -> Open with Encoding и выберите нужную кодировку.
Кроме того, смените настройку `"show_encoding": false` на `"show_encoding": true` и сможете видеть текущую кодировку файла в статусной строке саблайма.